# Referencing other studies in background

Tags: background

I am applying for a provisional patent application. Am I allowed to use problems from other studies in my Background/Problems section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but probably not copied word-for-word.

Copying another person's text word-for-word could well be copyright infringement, at least in theory. It certainly wouldn't be a good look. Copyright issues are off-topic for this site however.

However, I can't see that using the problems identified in other studies in your own words would raise any problems. Indeed, it arguably shows that you're solving a previously unsolved problem in the art, which suggests non-obviousness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one more question; should the study be referenced, and where in the application.

Comment: Whether to identify prior art in your application is a controversial point which intelligent people can differ on. You can see the different, equally correct points of views in the answers [here](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/14394/benefit-of-omitting-drawing-and-patent-number-of-prior-art-in-background) and [here](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/12050/citing-art-in-body-of-application/12174). If you were to reference it, it would be in the background section.